# Different thresholds for different parts of an image in image trace

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I used image trace, parts of the image are much more intense than others, I was wondering if I could have different thresholds for different parts of the image?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You could try editing the raster image first before you trace it.  Perhaps using the dodge and burn tools in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't "split" a trace in that manner.

*However*, You **can** trace the image 3 separate times with different settings then, once it's all vector, combine the portions you want and remove other portions.